# Cannot cast org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator to org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot cast org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator to 
org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator
```

Stack trace:

```
   [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'XXX threw an unexpected exception: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator to org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator to org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:370)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:438)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:76)
    at com.orangeraft.hms.server.module.login.service.LoginServiceImpl.login(LoginServiceImpl.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator to org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3007)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:362)
    ... 34 more
```

Here is my code:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure();
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
        .buildServiceRegistry();
SessionFactory sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
Session hibernateSession = sf.getCurrentSession();
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(hibernateSession);
    fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

I'm just trying to create the index as shown in the hibernate search tutorial [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en/html_single/#d0e350) in a GWT application. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I found this related post: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8970?focusedCommentId=76049&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-76049

Answer (score 4):

I'm thinking you have hibernate in both your WEB-INF/lib and on the launch classpath.  This may confuse the classloader as the implementation and the interface may not be loaded by the same classloader, thus giving an unexpected ClassCastException.

Comment: Thanks, JP.  Worked after I removed a "hibernate-core" maven dependency that was already supplied by another service jar.